# Accessing Activity components from non-activity class

Tags: java, android, android-context

I am trying to obtain Accelerometer's raw data and show it on a TextView.

I have two classes: MainActivity and SensorActivity. I am new to Android development and I made SensorActivity class intentionally just to learn how non-activity class and activity class interact. To do so, I learned, by searching, that I need to pass the Context of the MainActivity, so that SensorActivity class can interact with the MainActivity. So, I tried as far as I could, but I seem to get stuck.

In initialize function, my effort to get an access to a TextView of MainActivity doesn't seem to work. I cannot even make the correct syntax. Codes snippets are provided below. If I could get any help, it would be appreciated, tremendously.

In MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SensorActivity sensorActivity = new SensorActivity(this);
        sensorActivity.initialize();
    }
}
```

In SensorActivity.java

```
public class SensorActivity implements SensorEventListener{

    Context mainActivityContext;
    private SensorManager mySensorManager = (SensorManager) mainActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    public SensorActivity (Context context){
        this.mainActivityContext = context;
    }
    ...
    protected void initialize(){
        ...
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Activity Context for accessing View from non Activity class as:

```
protected void initialize(Activity activity){
    ...
    TextView tv = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
    ...
}
```

because `findViewById` is method from Activity class instead of Context

Comment: For me to do so, should I make an instance of Activity from the MainActivity.java and pass it like, sensorActivity(activity_instance)?

Comment: @ElectroJunkie : No, if you want to use Activity context in whole SensorActivity then just change only in SensorActivity :  `Context mainActivityContext;` to Activity mainActivityContext; and  `SensorActivity (Context context)`  to  `SensorActivity (Activity context)`

Comment: In initial function, I have a toast which requires - I think - a context. In this case, if I switch Context to Activity, how should I go about it?

Comment: @ElectroJunkie : then add two parameters one for Activity and other for Context in SensorActivity class constructor

Comment: Thank you. That question, I asked without thinking, he... XD

Comment: May I ask one more question, please. Now, I am instantiating SensorActivity with Activity and Context as arguments. Would you normally do this? This seems? feels? inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

**Use Activity reference instead of Context it will work.**